# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UISplitViewController: 0x133630>

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I load a splitViewController on my iPad app. But loading it with an empty data array.

Then I load a login view and when authenticated successfully I refresh the root and detail view. And because you are authenticated, it is loaded with data.

But while I load the Login view modally I get this error:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UISplitViewController: 0x133630>
```

code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...

//init
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

    //login
    LoginViewController *loginView = [LoginViewController new];
    [loginView setDelegate:self];
    loginView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; //this is still pushing the view horizontally in landscape?
    [self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];
...

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

When I comment-out the login load and push, I don't get the error.

But the weirdest thing is that it worked before, but after optimizations of the code this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but you need to

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

before presenting the modal view controller